# Interpreting Perf-log: CYCLES_L1D_MISS vs STALL_L1D_MISS

Tags: perf

I have some difficulties interpreting my output of perf and consulted the Intel manual.
How is it possible, that I have a higher number of L2-miss cycles than stalls? In my understanding a stall occurs because of the absence of a certain resource and the CPU has to wait for some cycles to continue working, but how can it stall more often and wait in average less than 1 cycle?

What's my blind spot?

```
FloatMatrixMatrixMultiplication.mmBaseline:CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L1D_MISS     128  sample          847972.191                 #/op
FloatMatrixMatrixMultiplication.mmBaseline:CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L2_MISS      128  sample            2715.740                 #/op
FloatMatrixMatrixMultiplication.mmBaseline:CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L3_MISS      128  sample             469.392                 #/op
FloatMatrixMatrixMultiplication.mmBaseline:CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L1D_MISS     128  sample            9839.128                 #/op
FloatMatrixMatrixMultiplication.mmBaseline:CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L2_MISS      128  sample            4534.397                 #/op
FloatMatrixMatrixMultiplication.mmBaseline:CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L3_MISS      128  sample             816.202                 #/op
FloatMatrixMatrixMultiplication.mmBaseline:CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_TOTAL        128  sample           11711.435                 #/op
```

Comment: Your table shows a **lower** number in the `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L2_MISS` row than  `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L2_MISS`.  (Which is weird; not all cycles when a demand load is in flight should be stalled, that's the whole point of out-of-order exec and non-blocking caches with hit-under-miss and miss-under-miss.) The CPU doesn't stall until the ROB or RS is full, or it runs out of load or store buffers to allocate new uops, and no uops exec; https://agner.org/optimize/ and https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/.  Skylake for example has 12 LFBs to track incoming / outgoing cache lines to L1d

Comment: Exactly, my conclusion.

Comment: If that's your conclusion, why did you ask the opposite thing?  Your question says you have a higher number of L2-miss cycles than stalls, the opposite of what your table shows.

Comment: hmm, now i am confused...
Why is my number of L2_MISS stalls higher than the cycles of the L2_MISS? But I understand that there is pipelining and out-of-order execution...